# Trying to instantiate objects within for loop and failing

Tags: java, object, loops, for-loop

Basically I am trying to create a new class as long as the continue variable equals "Y". The problem I am having is

```
DigitalMain.java:18: not a statement
    DigitalPhoto[] class = new DigitalPhoto[9];
```

upon compile. I have looked at ArrayLists but I am not quite sure if they would instantiate classes the same way as what I am trying to achieve. In an ideal situation I would have objects with the name "class"+i, and different values for every object via their built in set methods.

```
// Import classes for class
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DigitalMain
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String cont = "Y";
    String heightString,widthString,width,bitpsString;
    double bitps,x,y,totesPrice,totesSize,totesSpeed;
    DecimalFormat wholeDigits = new DecimalFormat("0");
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    DigitalPhoto[] picc = new DigitalPhoto[20];
    for(int i=0; cont.equals("Y") ; i++)
    {
    picc[i] = new DigitalPhoto();
    heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter height");
    picc[i].setHeight = Double.parseDouble(heightString);
    heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter width");
    picc[i].setWidth = Double.parseDouble(widthString);
    continueQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Height: " + picc[i].getHeight + "\n Width: " + picc[i].getWidth + "\n Resolution: " + picc[i].getResolution + "\n Compression Ratio: " + picc[i].getCompression + "\n Required Storage: " + picc[i].calcStorage() + "\n Price of Scanned Photo: " + picc[i].getCost() + "Please enter 'Y' to try again or anything but 'Y' to accept values.");
    };


    do
    {
    bitpsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your internet connection speed. Must be an integer between 1 and 99999999");
    bitps = Double.parseDouble(bitpsString);
    } while (bitps > 0 && bitps < 99999999);
    picc0.setSpeed(bitps);

    for(y = 0; y<picc.length; y++) {
      totesPrice += picc+y.getCost();
      totesSize += picc+y.calcStorage();
      totesSpeed = picc0.getSpeed();
    }

    double seconds = transferTime(totesSize, totesSpeed);
    double minutes = seconds / 60;
    double realsec = seconds % 60;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You will be paying: " + totesPrice + "\nRequired Storage is: " + totesSize + "Required time for transfer is: " + wholeDigits.format(minutes) + " minutes, and " + wholeDigits.format(realsec) + " seconds.");

  }

  public static double transferTime(double totalStorage, double netSpeed) {
    double bits, seconds;
    bits = (totalStorage * 8);
    seconds = (bits / netSpeed);
    return seconds;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely the name of your array. The word `class` is a keyword in the Java language and hence cannot be used to name variables. You can also use `ArrayLists` like so:

```
List<DigitalPhoto> photoes = new ArrayList<DigitalPhoto>(); 
do
    {
    DigitalPhoto photo = new DigitalPhoto();
    heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Please enter height');
    photo .setHeight = double.parseDouble(heightString);
    heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Please enter width');
    photo .setWidth = double.parseDouble(widthtString);
    photos.add(photo)
    continueQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Height: ' + class[i].getHeight + '\n\lWidth: ' + class[i].getWidth + '\n\l Resolution: ' + class[i].getResolution + '\n\lCompression Ratio: ' + class[i].getCompression + '\n\lRequired Storage: ' + class[i].calcStorage() + '\n\lPrice of Scanned Photo: ' + class[i].getCost() + 'Please enter "Y" to try again or anything but "Y" to accept values.')
    } while {cont.equals("Y")};
```

Answer (score 3):

`class` is a keyword - you can't use it as a variable name.

Additionally, you have an odd construct here:

```
for(int i=0; cont.equals("Y") ; i++)
{
    ...
} while {continue.equalsIgnoreCase(Y)};
```

There's no such thing as a "for/while" loop - there's a normal `for` loop, a `while` loop, and  a `do`/`while` loop.

So you've *actually* got a `for` loop followed by an invalid `while` loop here. It has no condition.

You need to work out which you want. (Possibly a for loop *containing* a do/while loop, although I'd extract the inner loop into a separate method. In general your code would greatly benefit from being broken out into multiple methods.

You do something similar later, although this time with `do`/`while`:

```
do
{
    ...
} while {bitps > 0 && bitps < 99999999};
```

The condition of a `while` loop goes in *round* brackets, not braces:

```
do
{
    ...
} while (bitps > 0 && bitps < 99999999);
```

Basically, you should read up on the syntax options available for loops.

Comment: HAHAHA wow. Thank you besides the myriad of other errors I have that seems to have fixed among the most egregious of offenders. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What kind of loop you are using.

```
for(...)
{
...
}while();
```

There is no `for-while` loop.

And also your `for` loop condition never going to become false. Set a proper condition to your for loop. 
Also there is syntax error in your `for-while` loop. ie. last statement

```
continueQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Height: ' + class[i].getHeight + '\n\lWidth: ' + class[i].getWidth + '\n\l Resolution: ' + class[i].getResolution + '\n\lCompression Ratio: ' + class[i].getCompression + '\n\lRequired Storage: ' + class[i].calcStorage() + '\n\lPrice of Scanned Photo: ' + class[i].getCost() + 'Please enter "Y" to try again or anything but "Y" to accept values.') // you miss the ;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is some rules for naming of variables [Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

```
 You cannot use any of the following(in list of keywords) as identifiers in your
 programs.The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not 
 currently used. true, false, and null might seem like keywords, but they 
 are actually literals;      you cannot use them as identifiers in your programs.
```

[List of keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

```
for(int i=0; cont.equals("Y") ; i++)
 {
   class[i] = new DigitalPhoto();
   heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Please enter height');
   class[i].setHeight = double.parseDouble(heightString);
   heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Please enter width');
   class[i].setWidth = double.parseDouble(widthtString);
   continueQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog('Height: ' + 
   class[i].getHeight + '\n\lWidth: ' + class[i].getWidth + '\n\l Resolution: ' +
   class[i].getResolution + '\n\lCompression Ratio: ' +  class[i].getCompression +
  '\n\lRequired Storage: ' + class[i].calcStorage() + '\n\lPrice of Scanned Photo: ' + 
    class[i].getCost() + 'Please enter "Y" to 
   try again or anything but "Y" to accept values.')
} while {continue.equalsIgnoreCase(Y)};
```

here i dont know any `for-while` loop..just check some basics..
[Loops in java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)